# Nova Scotia Announces New Immigration Stream - Canada

Tags: canada, immigration, canadian-citizens

I would like to avail the opportunity of this program as this does not require Job offer from Canada.

As per this program, applicant is eligible to apply (with 67 points) for "Nova scotia province" which is part of East Canada.

With the given [message](http://www.cicnews.com/2015/01/introducing-nova-scotia-demand-express-entry-014370.html) here:

```
 Nova Scotia Demand: Express Entry is aligned with Citizenship and Immigration Canada’s (CIC) Express Entry immigration selection system, which came into operation last week.
    Potential candidates have the benefit of two application routes for the Nova Scotia Demand: Express Entry stream. They may either:
    1) apply directly to the Nova Scotia Office of Immigration (NSOI) and then enter the Express Entry pool with a provincial nomination, which will trigger an invitation to apply for permanent residence; or
    2) be selected from the Express Entry pool by the NSOI.

In the latter case, when candidates create an Express Entry profile, they will be prompted to select their desired destination(s) in Canada, as well as details of their education and work experience. The NSOI will be able to browse candidates in the pool and may select candidates based on the information they provided when creating their profile.
```

With respect to second point above, I have already selected “Nova Scotia” province as part of express entry application form.

In addition to this express entry profile, as per the first point, does it add any value if I apply directly to the Nova Scotia Office of Immigration (NSOI)? If yes, please help me understand the application process.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to contact the Nova Scotia immigration office to confirm. Based on the paragraph that you included above (and I've looked at the originating website, you don't have to also apply directly with NSOI if you've already applied for the Federal Express Entry and included that you'd like to emigrate to Nova Scotia.

NSOI is able to search the Express Entry pool of candidates and see any that have selected Nova Scotia as a desired destination.

Comment: yes i have selected Nova scotia as destination in my express entry profile, but additionally, Do u suggest me to directly apply to Nova scotia office?

Comment: there could be a possibility where Nova scotia office already received required applicant forms and would not require to pick from express entry pool.